# Is there a way to map the json key from the web api response using java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get data from web API and somehow map it to entity but I'm having a hard time with mapping the key from json file.

This is how I get data,

```
  String api = "https://...";
  URL url = new URL(api);
  logger.info("API : {}", api);

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  conn.connect();

  int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

  if (responseCode != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " + responseCode);

  } else {
    StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    // Close the scanner 
    scanner.close();

    logger.info("informationString: {}", informationString);
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "Christmas Day": {
    "datum": "2022-12-25",
    "hinweis": ""
  },
  "New Year's Day": {
    "date": "2023-01-01",
    "desc": ""
  },
  "Valentines Day": {
    "date": "2022-02-14",
    "desc": ""
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Can you please help me map the keys with the dates with the JSON response?

Comment: Why don't you deserialize this ?

Comment: how should I map the holidayName for all those keys?

Comment: You should deserialize this into a DTO or any java object.